# Gigabyte motherboard GA-EP45-UD3L cputemp and fan speed sensors not working

Tags: 12.04, sensors

For example, the system monitor add-on for cairo-dock shows 0 degrees and 0 rpm (although it does show the GPU temp on my video card).

...using Ubuntu Unity 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  I installed lm-sensors.  I ran `sensors-detect`, accepted the defaults, until at the end, I told it to update /etc/modules. Then `sudo service module-init-tools restart` got it all working. The command `sensors` tests it, and the numbers all now appear in apps like psensors and the system monitor in cairo dock sees CPU temp and fan speed.

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +48.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +43.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +43.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +43.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

it8718-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in1:          +1.89 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:          +3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
+5V:          +2.98 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:          +0.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in5:          +0.05 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in6:          +0.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in7:          +3.17 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
Vbat:         +3.01 V  
fan1:        1896 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +39.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +42.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:         -2.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM
```